# Virtualbox Seamless mode grayed out

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Windows 8.1 host, and I am trying to get it to work with seamless mode. Using latest version of VirtualBox.

I have guest additions installed on the guest, and when entering a program and looking at the "view" menu, the "Seamless Mode" line is grayed out. The hotkey combination doesn't work either.

I double checked that the program is focused and things like that, also rebooted a couple of times. Also disabled nested paging.

Is there any way to test if the guest additions are working? Also, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failure to switch to seamless mode indicates a missing or incomplete installation of the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

In light weight Ubuntu variants we may not have a **gcc** compiler installed to compile the additions for the guest. This is provided with the package [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=build-essential) that we have to install in the guest before we can install the guest additions.

A missing compiler may result in a `fail` message on running the guest additions install script.

After we had installed the guest additions without an error we need a reboot of the guest to be able to switch the *View* to *Seamless Mode*.

Comment: so what do I do exactly to confirm what's wrong?

Comment: Got it working, the mouse behaves strangely though, I will play around with it, maybe a resolution problem.